# Apply group by having order by with latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group by name column having order by date with the latest group first, for example

Data:

```
name|status|date
john|read  |07/23/2020
matt|read  |07/23/2020
john|print |07/24/2020
matt|print |07/24/2020
```

it should be displayed as:

```
name|status|date
john|print |07/24/2020
john|read  |07/23/2020
matt|print |07/24/2020
matt|read  |07/23/2020
```

Kindly assist me.

my attempt so far:

```
;with cte as(
    select status,name, date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date desc) RowID
    from @tbl
)

select status,name,timeStamp from cte
order by timeStamp desc,RowID desc
```

Comment: [Edit] your question, @MussadiqChhipa , don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by max(date) over(partition by name) desc, date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY [Date]) RN
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('john', 'print', '2020-07-24'),
    ('john', 'read', '2020-07-23'),
    ('matt', 'print', '2020-07-24'),
    ('matt', 'read', '2020-07-23')
  ) T(Name, Status, [Date])
)
SELECT Name, Status, [Date]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RN DESC;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6e21884846e18efc3f771a8eb9702a1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`.  But you probably also want to keep the names together when there are ties, so you need three keys:

```
order by max(date) over (partition by name) desc,
         name,
         date desc;
```

Note that you can also use other tie breakers.  For instance, when two names have the same most recent date, you can put the one with the most recent *earliest* date first with an additional key:

```
order by max(date) over (partition by name) desc,
         min(date) over (partition by name) desc,
         name,
         date desc;
```